# Force login through ssh only

Tags: login, pam, account-restrictions, accounts

I have a small problem. I have two accounts on a PC. One is used for "normal" operations, usually through the graphical interface, the other is only used for remote management (upload files through sftp, execute through ssh)

Now, I'd like to disable the local login for the second account and allow it to be used only through ssh and sftp. If this is unfeasible, I actually need that it can't login on the graphical interface (mainly because I don't want the X standard folders - Desktop, Downloads... - to appear in the home folder).

I'm using lubuntu (so LXDE as DE) 16.04 x64

Comment: So you want to disable local GUI and CLI login to second account or just local GUI login?

Comment: @coffeMug actually I need just to disable the GUI login, but I'd prefer to disable also the CLI, if this is easily doable

Comment: One ugly solution to disable gui login is to delete usr's home directory.

Comment: @coffeMug unluckily... I need that folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a group for the users you want to be able to log in graphically (just to make it easier if you decide to add another user later). I'll assume `graphical-users`, but the name doesn't matter.

1. Add the group: `addgroup graphical-users`
2. Add your normal user to this group: `adduser frarugi graphical-users`.
3. Edit your PAM config for lxdm (probably `/etc/pam.d/lxdm`) [or whatever login manager you're using, possibly lightdm] to add something like this, probably right below `@include common-auth`:

   ```
   auth required pam_succeed_if.so quiet_success user ingroup graphical-users
   ```

I confess I haven't tested this, and am hoping the PAM setup in Lubuntu is similar to Debian.

Comment: I confirm this is working on both Xubuntu and Lubuntu 16.04, both using lightdm (so the file is /etc/pam.d/lightdm). Since I also needed no login from XRDP, I had to add this line also to the file /etc/pam.d/sesman. Now I can login only from command line, which is fine for now. Thank you!